# Why does the loss of this multi-layered perceptron not go below 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, perceptron

I coded a multi-layered perceptron with 2 hidden layers.
I have a single layer version that seems to work properly but when I add the extra layer the loss doesn't seem to go below 1.

What I'm trying to achieve is a binary classification method for the MNIST dataset. More exactly I'm trying to use this MLP to distinguish between 3 and 7. I'm using a sigmoid activation function and backpropagation to adjust the weights.

I suspect that there might be something wrong with how I coded the backpropagation.

```
num_examples = len(X) # training set size
nn_input_dim = 784 # input layer dimensionality
nn_output_dim = 2 # output layer dimensionality

# Gradient descent parameters
epsilon = 0.005 # learning rate for gradient descent

def calculate_loss(model):
    W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3 = model['W1'], model['b1'], model['W2'], model['b2'], model['W3'], model['b3']

    # Forward propagation to calculate predictions
    z1 = X.dot(W1) + b1
    a1 = sigmoid(z1)
    z2 = a1.dot(W2) + b2
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    z3 = a2.dot(W3) + b3
    exp_scores = np.exp(z3)
    probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    # Calculate the loss
    corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(num_examples), y])
    data_loss = np.sum(corect_logprobs)

    return 1./num_examples * data_loss

def predict(model, X):
    W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3 = model['W1'], model['b1'], model['W2'], model['b2'], model['W3'], model['b3']

    #Forward propagation
    z1 = X.dot(W1) + b1
    a1 = sigmoid(z1)
    z2 = a1.dot(W2) + b2
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    z3 = a2.dot(W3) + b3
    exp_scores = np.exp(z3)
    probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return np.argmax(probs, axis=1)


def build_model(nn_hdim1, nn_hdim2, num_passes=20000, print_loss=False):

    # Initialize the params that need to be learned to random values
    np.random.seed(0)
    W1 = np.random.randn(nn_input_dim, nn_hdim1) / np.sqrt(nn_input_dim)
    b1 = np.zeros((1, nn_hdim1))
    W2 = np.random.randn(nn_hdim1, nn_hdim2) / np.sqrt(nn_hdim1)
    b2 = np.zeros((1, nn_hdim2))
    W3 = np.random.randn(nn_hdim2, nn_output_dim) / np.sqrt(nn_hdim2)
    b3 = np.zeros((1, nn_output_dim))

    # This is what we return at the end
    model = {}
    loss = []

    for i in range(0, num_passes):

        # Forward propagation
        z1 = X.dot(W1) + b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = a1.dot(W2) + b2
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        z3 = a2.dot(W3) + b3
        exp_scores = np.exp(z3)
        probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)

        # Back propagation
        delta4 = probs
        delta4[range(num_examples), y] -= 1
        dW3 = (a2.T).dot(delta4)
        db3 = np.sum(delta4, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        delta3 = delta4.dot(W3.T) * (1 - sigmoid(a2))
        dW2 = (a1.T).dot(delta3)
        db2 = np.sum(delta3, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        delta2 = delta3.dot(W2.T) * (1 - sigmoid(a1))
        dW1 = np.dot(X.T, delta2)
        db1 = np.sum(delta2, axis=0)

        # Gradient descent parameter update
        W1 += -epsilon * dW1
        b1 += -epsilon * db1
        W2 += -epsilon * dW2
        b2 += -epsilon * db2
        W3 += -epsilon * dW3
        b3 += -epsilon * db3

        # Assign new parameters to the model
        model = { 'W1': W1, 'b1': b1,
                  'W2': W2, 'b2': b2,
                  'W3': W3, 'b3': b3}

        if print_loss and i % 500 == 0:
          loss.append(calculate_loss(model))
          print("Loss after iter. %i: %f" %(i, calculate_loss(model)))


    return model, loss

model, loss = build_model(3, 3, num_passes=10000, print_loss=True)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
Loss after iter. 500: 2.115385
Loss after iter. 1000: 3.981505
Loss after iter. 1500: 4.851937
Loss after iter. 2000: 2.286764
Loss after iter. 2500: 0.650758
Loss after iter. 3000: 0.454743
Loss after iter. 3500: 2.034308
Loss after iter. 4000: 2.221124
Loss after iter. 4500: 0.486550
Loss after iter. 5000: 1.803266
Loss after iter. 5500: 2.318486
Loss after iter. 6000: 1.594879
Loss after iter. 6500: 3.081962
Loss after iter. 7000: 2.340241
Loss after iter. 7500: 3.693953
Loss after iter. 8000: 1.618758
Loss after iter. 8500: 2.328891
Loss after iter. 9000: 2.265693
Loss after iter. 9500: 3.503290
```

My expectation would be that after iteration 4500, where the loss is .4, the model would keep improving but this doesn't happen.

At first, it seems that the step is too large and the regression overshoots the convergence 'valley' but I think 0.005 is quite small, compared to what is usually used for this.

Comment: Did you try to use a smaller learning rate, like 1e-3 or 1e-4? I would recommend to try different learning rates in log scale. 
How many examples are you using?

Comment: the shape of  X is (12396, 784) so I have 12396 examples (3's and 7's) which are 28x28 images converted into arrays (hence the 784).
I'll run the examples with even lower learning rates and get back with the results. Thank you!